# How to convert a string into a long double?

Tags: c++, string, iostream, typeconverter, long-double

To start off, I have thoroughly examined other questions on that matter and nothing helped me. I need to convert a string into a long double type, and nothing works for me.

```
string a="634.232";
long double x;
x=strtold(a.c_str(),0);
```

For example: this "strtold" changes [this input](http://scr.hu/28fl/gmu57) into [this output](http://scr.hu/28fl/a0ipx).

Comment: It'd be easier for us to see those images as actual text instead of images.

Comment: Don't use `0` to indicate a null pointer. That's very poor hygiene.

Answer (score 4):

Check for errors:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

const char str[] = "634.232";

int main()
{
    char * e;
    errno = 0;
    long double val = std::strtold(str, &e);

    if (*e != '\0' || errno != 0) { /* error */ std::abort(); }

    std::cout << "SUccessfully parsed: " << val;
}
```

Note that string parsing can fail in multiple ways: The string may not, or not in its entirety, represent a number, or the number that it does represent may be too large to fit into the data type. You have to check for all those possibilities, which is what this code is doing. The end pointer `e` checks that we've consumed the entire string, and the `errno` checks that the conversion succeeded.

Comment: [Demo](http://ideone.com/cTgbzO), [Demo with `std::string`](http://ideone.com/4cD5kF).

Comment: But I need to convert a string, typically string, not an array of chars. It makes difference in my project.

Comment: @NWafel: Isn't that like complaining that you want to see a movie, not images played in a sequence with a soundtrack? Did you see the second demo? You can get a view of the underlying array from an `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

`strtold` should work fine, as [KerrekSB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) suggests.

But while you're checking your work I'd recommend using `stold`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stold/

```
string a{"634.232"};
long double x{stold(a)};
```

Comment: Might want to wrap the call to `stold` in a `try` - `catch` block.

Comment: @user657267 That's a great call actually, error handling isn't available in C, so that's another benefit that you'll get from using `stold`.

Comment: @JonathanMee: "error handling isn't available in C" is a statement I would regard with a grain of skepticism (especially given that I just described in detail how to handle all kinds of specific errors through the C interface).

Comment: How to use this in for?


long double x[15];
string a[15];
for (;;)
{
?
}

Comment: @NWafel so looking at your code you first need to initialize all 15 `std::string`s. Then you could do something like: `transform(begin(c),end(c),begin(a),bind(static_cast<long double(*)(const string&,size_t*)>(&stold),placeholders::_1,nullptr));` Shown here: http://ideone.com/WxZtV8

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess I should qualify my error handling statement to say `stold` handles errors the C++ way, using `try`-`catch` right out of the box. Using `strtold` you'll need to go the C route of checking `errno`, and then throwing your own error if you want to use `try`-`catch`.